# Creating a triangle ios swift View

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to replicate the layer or view in iOS swift(the one saying follow and or the view with the followers)that is in the red box but i dont know really how to approach this.Should I try by making a view to then making it triangular?

[image]

Comment: Do you know about masks? Try to do it with mask

Comment: This isn't a "teach me how to code" site. It's a site to get help with code that you have written. You could do this with Core Graphics, or with CALayers and masks. Do some reading.

Comment: thanks @DuncanC I appreciate your input.

Comment: There are also tools that can help here: https://www.paintcodeapp.com/ or https://graphic.com/mac/ (formerly iDraw)  I know paintcode exports the core graphics drawing code, and iDraw did (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvElfya_hSA) I don't know if AutoDesk killed that feature or not. Aside from the better solutions of using Core Graphics, you could also just export a PNG of this. Naturally that comes with it's own issues, principally maintaining the 2x 3x sizes etc. If you are not familiar with Core Graphics  this may be faster for you to implement but is arguably not the best solve.

Answer (score 0):

-Try the following code

```
import UIKit

class animationView: UIView {
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
let path = UIBezierPath()
path.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 80, y: 50))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 140, y:150))
path.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 10, y:150))
path.closePath()

UIColor.greenColor().setFill()
UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
path.lineWidth = 3
path.fill()
path.stroke()
}
}
```

- You should have a triangle after this. Adjust the point's x and y value to correctly match your requirements.